# Query performance; not sure what's happening

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

I had issues with my query that took 17 seconds to execute (350k rows):

```
SELECT idgps_unit, MAX(dt) 
         FROM gps_unit_location
        GROUP BY 1
```

Explain

```
1   SIMPLE  gps_unit_location   index       fk_gps2 5       422633
```

After playing with it, I came with this solution that takes 1second:

```
Select idgps_unit, MAX(dt) from (
SELECT idgps_unit,  dt
         FROM gps_unit_location
) d1
Group by 1
```

Explain:

```
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 423344  Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED gps_unit_location   index       gps_unit_location_dt_gpsid  10      422617  Using index
```

And now I am confused- why query #2 is fast, while query #1 seems to be the same query and seems to be written more efficiently.

Index1 :DT, Index2: idgps_unit, Index3: idgps_unit+DT

The execution times are consistent; query #1 always takes 17-19sec; while #1 <1sec.

I am using Godaddy VPS Windows Server 2008 Economy

Table example:

```
id | idgps_unit | dt | location
1 | 1 | 2012-01-01 | 1
2 | 1 | 2012-01-02 | 2
3 | 2 | 2012-01-03 | 3
4 | 2 | 2012-01-04 | 4
5 | 3 | 2012-01-05 | 5
```

Comment: Is the execution time for both queries are consistent?  Because it is possible that the results are cached when the first query was executed and used by second query.

Comment: If you could post the result of running `EXPLAIN` on those queries, it could be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to get the `dt` and `idgps_unit` from the latest entry (assuming `dt` is a timestamp)? If so, you should rewrite the query; the way you're doing it now doesn't really make sense and an `ORDER BY...LIMIT` query would be faster and actually make sense.

Comment: @G-Nugget , `LIMIT` limits results. The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: @Andrew I guess I should rephrase my question: What are you trying to get with the query?  They way you're using the `GROUP BY` is technically incorrect and can lead to inaccurate results.  Strictly, you can't select non-aggregate values from `GROUP BY` queries, but MySQL provides a work around that you're using here.

Comment: @Andrew So using your example, are you expecting to get `1, 2012-01-05`?

Comment: @G-Nugget, no it should contain 3 latest records with each `idgps_unit`

Comment: @andrew I see now, the `GROUP BY 1` is synonymous with `GROUP BY idgps_unit` and you're not just using it to group the entire table into one group.  I've never seen a `GROUP BY` written like that.

Comment: What is the definition of `fk_gps2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming `gps_unit_location` is really a table and not a view.  Second, I'm also assuming that you have run both queries multiple times, so caching is the not explanation.  (Caching would be that you run the first query, it loads the table into page cache and the second reads from memory rather than disk.)

Do you have an index on `gps_unit_location(idgps_unit)`?  Are the records very wide?  If the answers to these questions are "yes", then the following may be happening.

If so, you might have a curious problem with indexing.  You would think that an index would speed up such a query.  What it does, though, is to look up the values in `idgps_id` in order.  If the index does not contain the date, then the database needs to fetch the data from each page.  If the table does not fit into memory, then this will often result in a cache-miss -- that is, time to load the page.

By contrast, if the table is wide and the engine does a full table scan, then it can zip through the table and extract the two fields of interest.  It puts them on the side.  If they are small relative to the full table, then sorting them might take very little time.  Voila, the query finishes faster.

My guess would be that the second structure removes the use of an index.

By the way, you can fix this by changing the index to `gps_unit_location(idgps_unit, dt)`.  By including the field in the index, the query does not have to load the data.

Comment: `gps_unit_location(idgps_unit, dt)` solved the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would say your indexs are not set up properly, Your second query is kind of an inner query which is effectively creating its own inner index group if that makes sense !